# Get(), set() methods make JButton and JTable can not be displayed on JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I organized my example Project to practice MVC pattern. Model package I stored class "Student", model view I stored a `JFrame` called "ExampleView", controller I stored a class "ExampleController".

In `JFrame` "ExampleView", I have a `button(btnGetAllInfo)` and a table(tblGetAll). 
This is my source code for "ExampleView"

```
 package View;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JTable;
public class ExampleView extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTable tblGetAllStudentInfo;
    private JButton btnGetAllInformation;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    ExampleView frame = new ExampleView();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public ExampleView() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        this.contentPane = new JPanel();
        this.contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(this.contentPane);
        this.contentPane.setLayout(null);

        this.btnGetAllInformation = new JButton("Get all information");
        this.btnGetAllInformation.setBounds(159, 11, 128, 23);
        this.contentPane.add(btnGetAllInformation);

        this.tblGetAllStudentInfo = new JTable();
        this.tblGetAllStudentInfo.setBounds(24, 52, 384, 180);

        this.contentPane.add(this.tblGetAllStudentInfo);
    }

    public JPanel getContentPane() {
        return contentPane;
    }

    public void setContentPane(JPanel contentPane) {
        this.contentPane = contentPane;
    }

    public JTable getTblGetAllStudentInfo() {
        return tblGetAllStudentInfo;
    }

    public void setTblGetAllStudentInfo(JTable tblGetAllStudentInfo) {
        this.tblGetAllStudentInfo = tblGetAllStudentInfo;
    }

    public JButton getBtnGetAllInformation() {
        return btnGetAllInformation;
    }

    public void setBtnGetAllInformation(JButton btnGetAllInformation) {
        this.btnGetAllInformation = btnGetAllInformation;
    }
}
```

When I run `JFrame` "ExampleView" with no `getBtnGetAllInfo()` and `getTblGetAllStudentInfo()` methods, I got this below result

[image]

And corresponding result with `getBtnGetAllInfo()` and `getTblGetAllStudentInfo()` methods, I got this below result

[image]

Can anyone explain to me why when I have get(), set() methods for button and table like I do above, my button and table do not be shown?

Comment: please post the relevant code in the question, don't link to other pages or print screens. also: try to be more clear on what you are talking about

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). And please add it as a **text** [edit] to the question, as @Stultuske suggests, not images.

Comment: Thank @ Stultuske and @Andrew Thompson for giving me advise to format my question. I've edited done. Could you help me to answer my question, please?

Comment: Addind method don't change the result, but if you also use this getter to add into the layout, this could be intersting to see what it looks like for both result (both capture). Adding a method that is never call can only prevent the code to compile, it would not change the behavior of another method (unless we start mentionning overloading / overriding of course).

Comment: By the way you should NOT be using a null layout and setBounds(...). Notice how the text of the button is truncated. This is because you don't know the size of the text. Use a proper layout manager and it will display the component so the text is NOT truncated.

Comment: @ AlexH I want to call `getBtnGetAllInfo()` and`getTblGetAllInfo()` methods in my controller which include "ExampleController" class, so I think it is the only way to call out button to implement `addActionListener()` method.

Comment: Please provide a small [mcve] with the two screen you have shown. Like I said, adding a getter would not change the result of `ExampleView` constructor, unless you are calling `this.contentPane.add(getBtnGetAllInformation());` without setting the bounds.